# ItemsControl groups in tabs

Tags: wpf, tabcontrol, itemscontrol

I need to display primary groups of itemscontrol as tabs.

There is an ItemsControl.GroupStyle property that contains GroupStyle with GroupStyle.Panel property.

In essence I would like to achieve this:

```
<ItemsControl>
  <ItemsControl.GroupStyle>
    <GroupStyle>
      <GroupStyle.Panel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
          <TabControl/> <!-- (1) -->
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
      </GroupStyle.Panel>
      <GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
          <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
              <ControlTemplate>
                <TabItem Header="{Binding Name}"> <!-- (2) -->
                  <TabItem.Content>
                    <ItemsPresenter />
                  </TabItem.Content>
                </TabItem>
              </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
          </Setter>
        </Style>
      </GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
    </GroupStyle>
  </ItemsControl.GroupStyle>
</ItemsControl>
```

Unfortunately there are two problems with this:

1. TabControl is not a Panel
2. TabItem inside GroupItem.Template is packed inside GroupItem but tabcontrol exptects only TabItems.

Answer (score 2):

A partial solution I have found so far is to use TabControl with ItemsSource bound to CollectionView.Groups and inside TabControl.ContentTemplate use ItemsControl bound to current group Items:

```
<TabControl ItemsSource="{Binding MyItems, Converter={StaticResource CollectionToViewGroupsConverter}}"
            SelectedIndex="0">
    <TabControl.ContentTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type CollectionViewGroup}">
            <ContentControl>
                <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Items}"/>
            </ContentControl>
        </DataTemplate>
    </TabControl.ContentTemplate>
</TabControl>
```

Where converter is:

```
public class CollectionToViewGroupsConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var view = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(value);
        if (view == null)
            return null;
        return view.Groups;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Unfortunately this is all part of another template and my ItemsControl contains a lot of references to TemplatedParent which are now invalid since it is now a template for TabControl.

Answer (score 0):

Problem 1 is not too hard to solve - TabControl uses a TabPanel internally, so you can hook it up like so :

```
<GroupStyle.Panel>
    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
        <TabPanel />
    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
</GroupStyle.Panel>
```

This will get you headered tabs, which is progress, I hope :)

Problem 2 and getting the tab content itself to show up is a bit more challenging.  It may be worth trying a converter, or shenannigans with the ItemContainerGenerator.  I'll update my post if anything clever occurs to me.